# How to sent dynamic html table data from html form to php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

i got some problem in sending the html table value as form data to the php file.
My problem is..

i have dynamic html tables(which are more than 20 tables) which are created by javascript.
This dynamic tables has dynamic data which is entered by the user. Here i am saving these dynamic data in to the tables.(which is in the table row and table column tags).

Here is my doubt is how to send the these dynamic data tables to my PHP file..

Here my data attributes are dynamic (like id, name and class).

I searched in the google.com and i found the one solution. some thing like place the hidden input tag in your table..

if i do that i will get one more problem.

as previously i said that my data attributes are dynamic. if i do the hidden input values how can i get those value to php file..

I mean, suppose i have 20 rows in each table if send those data to php file, how can i find which data is belong to which table..

Here my every table has 20 rows each. Each row has the dynamic name(which is same to all 20 rows in a table).

please suggest the best way to get rid of this problem.

[image: Here is my Output]

Comment: Show us some code and please be specific.

Comment: i added the screenshot of my output..
in that i have more than 15 departments..
that means 15 tables are created dyanmically..

Comment: Title is not apt to the question and you have to improve the question to provide more information so that we can understand and guide you to a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be, you can loop all the tables and get the values of the first four table cells(TD) for each row in the table, assuming all the tables have same columns, and generate a <strike>json</strike> javascript object and send that object to your server via javascript.

sample:

```
var data = {
'department1': {
    'eventname': 'xyz',
    'emailid': 'x@xyz.com',
    'registrationfee' : '300',
    'studentname': 'me',
    'contactno': '999999999'
 }, 
'department2': {
   'eventname': 'xyz2',
    'emailid': 'y@xyz.com',
    'registrationfee' : '500',
    'studentname': 'me2',
    'contactno': '9999988888'
},
.....
};
```

and send the data via post ajax call using jquery or plain javascript.

You can access the data on the server side. If you are using a php framework it might automatically decode the json and gives you an array orthewise you might have to use json_decode().

Hope this gives you a fair idea on how to do it.

Edit:

> I mean, suppose i have 20 rows in each table if send those data to php file, how can i find which data is belong to which table..

On that, you are saying that the tables are generated from javascript for each department then add a data attribute to the table to identify the which department the table belongs.

```
<table data-department="department1"></table>
```